# Date in past prevent

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a date form in my application but need to prevent users from accidentally picking dates in the past. I have looked at the help and copied the suggested text into the range box but it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum and maximum range values in Cognito Forms can either be constant values, like `8/1/2015` or calculations, like `=DateTime.Today`.  Use this calculation as the minimum to prevent users from entering dates in the past.  The date picker will visually show these dates cannot be selected and an error will be shown if they try to type in a date in the past.

**Range Settings**

[image]

**Date Validation**

[image]